# How to run scrapy server as a daemon

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I am trying to run scrapy server as a daemon. I have tried [this link](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)  but i getting error 
whenever i run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install scrapyd-0.14
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package scrapyd-0.14
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'scrapyd-0.14'
```

I am able to run scrapy server from my scrapy project folder but i want to run it as background service (daemon)..i am using `scrapy version : Scrapy 0.16.5`

how do i do this...please help me..

Comment: And using OS `ubuntu 13.04`..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the Ubuntu repository first. Run the following commands under root permission:

```
$ curl -s http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
$ echo "deb http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu precise main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install scrapyd-0.14
```

Also note that the latest version of Scrapyd available up to date is 0.17

Comment: Now i am getting this error `W: GPG error: http://archive.scrapy.org precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7AECB5E990E2741A
`